# Error in creating superuser django

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to create a superuser in my sample django project using the command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username=admin --email=geopaulm@gmail.com
```

But I get an error as below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 105, in get_default_username
    default_username = get_system_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 85, in get_system_username
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 459, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 391, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: Check your environment variables.  Using "`env`", e.g.  `LANGUAGE`, `LC_ALL`, and `LANG` are all significant/relevant here.  should be compound, like `en_US.UTF8`, not just `UTF8`.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @FastTurtle Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 min google search and here it is:

[How to fix locale issue on MacOsX](http://patrick.arminio.info/blog/2012/02/fix-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf8/)

Please modify the locale name accordingly, maybe to en_US.UTF8 as in this link it's for italian.