# Error creating superuser in Django

Tags: python, django, command-line, django-admin

I am trying to create a superuser to access the Django admin framework in my app. I am using Vagrant on a Windows 8.1 machine:

```
> ./manage.py createsuperuser
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, i
n execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, i
n execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in ru
n_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in ex
ecute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsu
peruser.py", line 141, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/vagrant/myapp/accounts/managers.py", line 52, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
  File "/vagrant/myapp/accounts/managers.py", line 31, in _create_user
    user.set_slug()
  File "/vagrant/myapp/accounts/models.py", line 164, in set_slug
    slug = slugify(self.username, max_length=50).lower()
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slugify/main.py", line 101, in slugify
    text = join_words(words, separator, max_length)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/myapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slugify/main.py", line 78, in join_words
    text = next(words)    # text = words.pop(0)
StopIteration
```

I've read elsewhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931464/error-in-creating-superuser-django)) and ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952568/unable-to-create-superuser-after-syncdb)) that this is a "locale" issue, but my understanding this is a OSX bug and I'm on a vagrant virtual machine...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--username` flag instead of directly passing a username:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username thisismyusername
```

Comment: @alias51 What's the complete command you're running? Do you happen to have a custom user model?

Comment: it's `python manage.py createsuperuser` then I follow the prompts to enter email and password and get the above error. Yes I have a custom user model.

Comment: @alias51 Can you post your model?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, after migrating the changes I was able to create the super user.

Try this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Because you have not applied migrations after creating your model.
So run

`python manage.py makemigrations` and then
`python manage.py migrate`

Now migrations have been applied and you can create superuser by running

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Lite I removed the DB file and run the commands:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$ run python manage.py syncdb
```

The system would try to sync and would ask:

```
You have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers                  defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'yogesh'): 
Email address: yogesh.gupta38@gmail.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
```

I was facing the same problem and this stuff worked in my case.